# i have a problem to get exact number value using BigDecimal class in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one variable which is **BigDecimal abc** and i have store in database with column_name is ( abc decimal(30,20) ) using Hibernate. so when i save data with abc variable and value = 00.0000000000 it will store in database perfectly, but when i get from database using Hibernate it will store as **0E-10** in **BigDecimal abc** but i need exact store value in database.

if any one have solution for above problem ??

i have already try to seach in google and also in stackoverflow.

Comment: but 0E-10 = 0 so what is the problem?

Comment: Please show us what you are doing.

Comment: How are you converting the value when writing/reading from/to the database?

Comment: 0E-10 is 0 to the precision of 10 decimal places, as you provided in your input, so seems to me like this is actually a more precise result than simply it returning 0

Comment: @Antoniossss problem is i need exact value 0.00.0000000000 not 0E-10.

Comment: but that IS EXACT VALUE 0.00.0000000000=0=0E-10

Comment: Number formatting is different story.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31531227/1527544

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027467/double-value-0-0001-will-converto-1-0e-4-while-inserting-into-database), Double Multiplication can get the unexpected result. You will have to store it as string and when you retrieve it, you made the conversion and it will conserve the right value.

Comment: What is wrong with 0*1^-10 ? What is unexpected about it?